# Microsoft bot emulator azure AD oauth does not give options to select the account to log in

Tags: node.js, azure-active-directory, botframework

I developed a bot with microsoft bot framework nodejs version4. I used azure AD oauth connection for the bot authentication. Initially when I try to login it shows me list of account to authenticate, but now it shows the empty window and does not allow me to select the account, by default it selects recent logged in account.

I does not know why this happens.Need help to solve

[image: This is the screenshot of the bot emulator]

Comment: What version of Emulator are you using?

Comment: Bot Framework Emulator 4.4.1

Comment: Does it work when you click test connection?

Comment: I deployed my bot in azure, then I tested in skype channel, in skype also first time it ask for the list of accounts to login, but after next time it automatically takes the previous logged in  account. I think the problem is in azure AD

Comment: @TonyJu Please help me to resolve this problem

Comment: @TonyJu In azure AD oauth test connection also does not ask me any account to login. It just takes an already logged in account and show me the token.

Comment: @Prakash I followed this document and it works well. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=aadv2%2Ccsharp%2Cbot-oauth

Comment: @Prakash The sign in url is something like https://token.botframework.com/api/oauth/signin?signin=921d46120fe29d1a9d52***e967f899aaf64fa1a You can try to open it in a incognito window

Comment: @TonyJu Yes tried in incognito window for the first time when I click azure test connection, it ask me to enter the username and password then it shows the token, but for the next time it only showing the token, it is not asking me the account.

Comment: @TonyJu any other may be a problem?

Comment: This is expected behavior. Once someone is already signed in, it's not supposed to ask them to sign in again. If they want to sign in as someone else they have to log out first.

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: @KyleDelaney I am not working on this. But still not able to resolve this issue. Do you have any solution for that.

Comment: The solution is to log out

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Comment: @KyleDelaney you are right now only I found out that azure AD does not logout the user properly. I think it does not delete the session of the user. So only it does not allow me to login with another account. my redirect url is https://token.botframework.com/.auth/web/redirect so what may be the logout url? I searched many document where I cannot able to find related to this. Please tell me what may be logout url?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're having two issues.

First, you say you're getting a blank sign-in screen in Emulator. Bot Framework Emulator 4.4.1 has a bug involving OAuth cards: https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/issues/1544

Try configuring Emulator to use a magic code:

[image: Emulator settings]

Second, you say Skype is using a previously signed-in account. Please refer to the [samples](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/18.bot-authentication/dialogs/logoutDialog.js#L37) in order to see how to sign a user out.

```
const botAdapter = innerDc.context.adapter;
await botAdapter.signOutUser(innerDc.context, this.connectionName);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, will try your answer today and response back and accept your answer.

Comment: I came to know that my application was not logout properly as you before. So I have to provide a logout url to logout a user from my application. my login url is https://token.botframework.com/.auth/web/redirect and logout url is https://token.botframework.com/.auth/logout .But still not working may be I did not know whether my  logout url is correct ? What may be logout url?

Comment: @Prakash - Where are you putting that logout URL? Why aren't you following this document? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=aadv2%2Cjavascript%2Cbot-oauth#log-the-user-out

Comment: I followed the same steps which is in the document. But it is signed out the user properly. So in azure active directory -> app registration -> select our application -> Authentication -> Logout URL. Here this Logout URL is empty, so i have to fill with logout url so that it will properly logout the user..